# Finding norm of b given ||a||, ||a-b||, and ||a+b||?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $a$ and $b$ be vectors such that $||a|| = 5$, $||a+b|| = 7$, and $||a-b|| = 9$. Find $||b||$.

---

What I've Tried:  ( assuming * $=$ using a dot product)
I did some rearranging by using the difference of the $||a+b||$ and $||a-b||$ terms, and found that $a * b = -8$. However, I'm unsure on how to proceed from here to get ||b||.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using the standard Euclidean norm, just apply parallelogram identity.

Comment: @geetha290krm ... reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law